# Iterate and animate over two arrays per click at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, animation

i searched again 3 days how i can "Iterate and animate over two arrays per click at once". I have two arrays where one has my output classes from html and the second one has data from an XML file. I have a Button where i each click become one animation. But now i want iterate both same time and become 2 animations per click. I have already a headache from this, ;). Wich way to go? Some helping ideas, please? Thank you!

**Code-Snippet**

```
$('#Next').click(function() {

    $(theArray[arrayIndex++]).fadeIn("slow")
    //$(xmlToArray[arrayIndex++]).fadeIn("slow")
    }                           
    // arrayIndex = 0;
    console.log(theArray[arrayIndex]);
})
```

Comment: Could you please show a complete example we could try out. It's not very clear what you want to do or what those arrays are. The only obviously suspicious thing is that you access different indices of the arrays, unless that's the purpose (you increment the `arrayIndex` before using it again in the other array).

Comment: hello Juhana, thank you for your answer. here i have my whole code in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485786/how-to-attach-for-every-array-element-in-jquery-different-animationeffects-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate through all of them you need a for loop.

```
$('#Next').click(function() {
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<theArray.length && i < xmlToArray.length; i++){

            theArray[i].fadeIn("slow");
            xmlToArray[i].fadeIn("slow");
    }                           
});
```

If you only want to increase the index by one per click you are on the right path:

```
$('#Next').click(function() {

    $(theArray[arrayIndex++]).fadeIn("slow")
    $(xmlToArray[arrayIndex]).fadeIn("slow")
    }                           
});
```

Comment: Hello Tokam, thank you for your answer. Yes your second answer ist my goal. i tryed it but it doesn't work.

Comment: wow, i cannot edit my comment. Then here again:Hello Tokam, thank you for your answer. **Yes your second answer is my goal.** i tryed it but it doesn't work. I tried already many possibilites and if not i wouldn't ask you to help. if somebody couldn't understand my english, so sorry for this, :).

Comment: @Juhana&tokam: hi guys, i tried it at the night again and it works. Thank you very much! Finally i became a help, ;D.

Comment: Does your solution somehow differ from mine?

Comment: uhm, at the moment no. because i can see in the log that both arrays iterated same time per each click from every array one item. some side effects there, but at the moment not important for me. Important is it works, :D. I'm working now on the animation. when i'm done, i'll give it here free. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to first merge the two using

```
var thirdarray = firstarray.concat(secoundarray)
```

then iterate over them at once using

```
$.each(thirdarray , function(){....})
```